# Start function in different time

Tags: javascript

I would like that the code in the redirectWindow function start after I get the response of the  confirmationOrder() function. I tried like this but it's not working.
Thank you if you can help me :)

```
 async function redirectWindow() {
            await confirmationOrder();
            let buttonValidation = document.getElementById('btn-validation');
            console.log(buttonValidation);
            buttonValidation.addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.location.href = "confirm.html";
            })
        }
```

My confirmationOrder function :

```
function confirmationOrder() {
    let buttonValidation = document.getElementById('btn-validation');
    console.log(buttonValidation);
    buttonValidation.addEventListener('click', function () {
        getForm();
        dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ contact, products });
        console.log(dataToSend);
        postForm(dataToSend);
    })
}
```

Comment: There is no promises in the code so unclear how you can use await.... Why is confirmationOrder not just calling the redirect code when it is clicked?

Comment: `await` is not a magical catch-all that tells the interpreter to wait until every line of code in the target function has been touched. It should be used on exactly one type of value: *a Promise*. Your `confirmationOrder()` function doesn't return any value, let alone a Promise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I find a way and it's working (the use of await and async was a desperate try after a lot of try)

Answer (score 0):

You're awaiting a function that doesn't return a promise. I guess what you want is to `await` the user click...

```
function confirmationOrder() {
    return new Promise(done=>{
        let buttonValidation = document.getElementById('btn-validation');
        console.log(buttonValidation);
        buttonValidation.addEventListener('click', function () {
             getForm();
             dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ contact, products });
             console.log(dataToSend);
             postForm(dataToSend);
             done();
        })
    });
}
```

However, you're probably going to want to await `postForm()` too, which means you need to make sure that's returning a promise too. Read about how [async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) work.